# Reinstall an official package when custom one has overwritten it

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, debian

I recently installed the Debian packages produced by running `make deb-pkg` to compile my own version of the Ubuntu kernel. I had given the kernel the release version `3.19.0-21-secure`. All of the packages were installed with that in their names except one: `linux-libc-dev`. It appears that there is no version information that identifies that packages, meaning that my installation of my locally built `linux-libc-dev` package probably overwrote the official one.

I am hesitant about removing it because apt-get will remove all the packages that depend on it without asking me. I tried running `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-libc-dev` and I got this error:

```
Reinstallation of linux-libc-dev is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

I tried to see if apt-get can locate the official version at all using `sudo apt-get download linux-libc-dev` and I got:

```
E: Can't find a source to download version '3.19.0-21-secure-3' of 'linux-libc-dev:amd64'
```

Aptitude thinks that it's getting the correct package, but it isn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `apt-cache policy linux-libc-dev` to see what versions of the package are available.

Comment: @saiarcot895 In my haste, I actually just uninstalled it, but I have the feeling that I modified system defaults when I did it. Before I uninstalled it, in the Software Center, it said the package was installed on April 22 2015 (I installed Ubuntu in late May, though) and after reinstalling it, it said installed on June 26 2015. I have a feeling that that prior date is the same for all Ubuntu 15.04 installations. Now I want to know if I screwed up any default dates or whatever.